# Which PDF viewer from Ubuntu repository allows to print current view?

Tags: printing, pdf

I know that Adobe Acrobat Reader has useful feature for printing - it allows printing current view.
So if user opens some document and then selects some area, the viewer allows to print this area:

1. start zooming with *Marquee Zoom* tool

   [image: zoom start]
2. zoom the selection with mouse

   [image: zoom end]
3. set print settings

   [image: print settings]
4. get print out

   [image: print out]

   Note: PDF output is just an illustration, really I need result on real paper.

But I want to get the same result with free software.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid Acrobat. The following can "Print Current View" and is free, but not OSS: PDF Studio, see https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/download/

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a year and 2 months ago, but I just saw it, and I see it has never been answered.

So in case someone else wants a FREE tool to do the same thing, i.e. print a PDF at a zoomed setting to fill the page (like manuals for a product you own that are printed in tiny text in a little rectangle in the centre of an A4 page)..

Try Xreader.
It should be in your repo.  I am using xreader 2.4.4 in Mint 19.9.

File > Print > General lets you choose which Printer, which Pages to print, Number of copies etc,
From General tab, opening the page Setup tab lets you choose:
Single or Two Sided printing (if you printer supports Duplex)
and some other settings.

At the Bottom of the list is Scale.  In most cases around 200% works well on those little manuals.
To the RIGHT is a Preview button so you can see if you made the right scale (zoom) choice.

Hope this helps.
RossD  :-)